# Convert int (that is casted from enum) to string is giving enum value back as string

Tags: c#, casting, enums

I have following statement in my code

```
string str = ((int)(UserRating)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserRating), ques.UserResponse)).ToString()
```

I need to store a number in `str`. Something like `"1", "2" or "3"`.

My Enum declaration is as below:

```
public enum UserRating
{
    One = 1, Two, Three, Four, Five
}
```

Full statement is below:

```
UserResponse = (ques.Type == UserQuestionType.Rating ? ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserRating), ques.UserResponse)).ToString() : ques.UserResponse)
```

Comment: Clearly `ques.UserResponse` is already a number defined as a string, why bother casting at all here? Are you just double checking that it is infact a *valid* number? Also, `Enum` is already an `int` so you don't need to cast to `UserRating` and then to `int`.

Comment: @James `ques.UserResponse` may be a string with `One`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ah yeah of course, however, it's strange that you would store ratings as an enum and not just an integer...

Comment: @James- Sriram is correct. It can be `"one", "two" ...`

Comment: I agree with @james, no point in doing this. Why would you need it as a string?

Comment: @shashwat yeah I completely overlooked that. However, I don't see the need for an enum here. It seems an unnecessary step (unless your example is not your *real* enum).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I want this as string because I think I might change `One, Two, .., Five` to something like `Bad, Avg, Gud, Best` later on. That is why I am storing this in my database as number. But unfortunately, I have several kind of questions and my response can be any string. So datatype in table is nvarchar. But I want to store response as number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get "1" from your enum try:

```
UserRating.One.ToString("d");
```

If you want to get "One" from your enum (easier to match perhaps) just omit the parameter in `ToString()`:

```
UserRating.One.ToString();
```

And your full statement is altered like this:

```
UserResponse = (ques.Type == UserQuestionType.Rating ?
                ((UserRating)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserRating), ques.UserResponse)).ToString("d") : ques.UserResponse);
```

But be sure to test it on questions which type is equal to `UserQuestionType.Rating` (or put any always true statement for testing)

Comment: I really thought your solution should work. But `((UserRating)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserRating), ques.UserResponse)).ToString("d")` is giving `"One", "Two" ...`

Comment: what is value for `ques.UserResponse`? If I place "One" instead of it I get "1"

Comment: It can be any like `"One" ... "Five"`. 100% sure. I checked it

Comment: it really strange... I posted sample program on pastebin - check if you have diferent outcome http://pastebin.com/SJAPmtWC

Comment: I have updated full statement in my question. Please check it. May be this is something

Comment: oops my mistake. Actually condition was not true.. sorry.
I want to delete the question but I can't bcoz It has answers now

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string str = ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserRating), ques.UserResponse)).ToString();
```

You can cast an enum value to `int` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to use more than one line:

```
UserRating userResponseEnum = (UserRating)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserRating), ques.UserResponse);
int userRatingValue = (int) userResponseEnum;
string str = userRatingValue.ToString();
```

Comment: I want a one line solution. Coz this statement is inside if statement. But I still don't think this solution would work. Because its just an expanded version of what I have done already. Are you sure this would work..?